# RSpec Tests For Method Return & Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write two RSpec tests for two different problems that are much more advanced that what I'm used to writing.

What I'm trying to test within my controller:

```
def index
  @buildings ||= building_class.active.where(place: current_place)
end
```

My attempt at writing the RSpec test:

```
describe 'GET :index' do
    it "assigns @buildings" do
      @buildings ||= building_class.active.where(place: current_place)
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:buildings)).to eq([building])
  end
end
```

This test failed and wouldn't even run so I know I'm missing something.

---

My second test is needing to test the returned value of a class method. Here is what I am needing to test within the controller:

```
def class_name
  ABC::Accountant::Business
end
```

Here is my attempt at testing this method:

```
describe "class name returns ABC::Accountant::Business" do
  subject do
    expect(subject.class_name).to eq(ABC::Accountant::Business)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first test I would do something like this:

First, I would move that `.active.where(place: current_place)` to a scope (I'm guessing `building_class` returns `Building` or something like that):

```
class Building << ApplicationRecord
  scope :active_in, -> (place) { active.where(place: place)
```

Then it's easier to stub for the test

```
describe 'GET :index' do
  it "assigns @buildings" do
    scoped_buildings = double(:buildings)

    expect(Building).to receive(:active_in).and_return(scoped_buildings)

    get :index
    expect(assigns(:buildings)).to eq(scoped_buildings)
  end
end
```

Then your controller will do

```
@buildings ||= building_class.active_in(current_place)
```

This way you are testing two things: that the controller actually calls the scope and that the controller assigns the returned value on the `@buildings` variable (you don't really need to test the actual buidlings, you can test the scope on the model spec).

Personally, I feel like it would be better to do something like `@buildings = current_place.active_buildings` using the same idea of the scope to test that you are getting the active buildings of the current place.

---

EDIT: if you can't modify your controller, then the stubbing is a little different and it implies some chaining of methods that I don't like to explicitly test.

```
scoped_buildings = double(:buildings)

controller.stub_chain(:building_class, :active, :where).and_return(scoped_building)

get :index
expect(assings(:buildings)).to eq scoped_buildings
```

Note that now your test depends on a specific implementation and testing implementation is a bad practice, one should test behaviour and not implementation.

---

For the second, I guess something like this should work:

```
describe ".class_name" do
  it "returns ABC::Accountant::Business" do
    expect(controller.class_name).to eq(ABC::Accountant::Business)
  end
end
```

IMHO, that the method's name if confusing, `class_name` gives the idea that it returns a string, you are not returnin a name, you are returning a class. Maybe you can change that method to `resource_class` or something less confusing.

Comment: Good answer. Although I think it would be helpful to suggest transitioning from controller specs to system specs, explain the difference and provide an example spec.

Comment: I have to test it the way it is written so I cannot alter the controller method at this time. Is the testing still similar that way?

Comment: I have added an idea to stub multiple method calls using stub_chain, personally I don't like that but it's better than having no test at all haha.